# How to save space for accessory view but not show it on UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a label right below accessory view on UITableViewCell. It's a reusable cell i.e. in some cases, I show the disclosure indicator and in some cases I don't show it. If I set `cell.accessoryType = .none`, then the label shifts to right i.e. takes the place of accessory view.

I don't want to show the disclosure indicator, but still want to leave a blank space over there. Here is what I tried:

```
cell.accessoryView.alpha = 0
```

Setting just this, shows the disclosure indicator by default. If I do the below, then disclosure indicator goes away, but the label moves to right.

```
cell.accessoryView.alpha = 0
cell.accessoryType = .none
```

I want the label in it's place in the below cell, just want to hide the disclosure indicator. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: is this a custom table view cell you made (that you control the constraints for) or the Default table view cell or?

Comment: It's a custom table view cell... but I am reusing the cell at multiple places i.e. in some cases I show the accessory type and in some cases I don't want to. One option is to create another custom cell and always have the accessory view hidden and add constraints to the label, but I was seeing if I can still use the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not is the greatest code but, since there's no answer, maybe this will help someone. Something like that is working for me in the cell file:

```
let option = UICellAccessory.LabelOptions.init(isHidden: false, reservedLayoutWidth: .standard, tintColor: nil)

    
accessories = state.isSelected ? [.checkmark()] : [.label(text: "", options: option)]
```

We display an accessory .label for when the cell is not selected, we set the text to nil but add a reservedLayoutWidth to its options, that will save us the needed space for the checkmark